# Replacing '?' with nothing

Tags: python-3.x

I have "?35249509094742" in a column and I want to remove '?' from it so as to have a number "35249509094742". Why I cannot remove the '?' with

```
df8.replace({ "IMEI1": "?" }, 0)
```

I have also tried

```
df8.replace({ "IMEI1": "?35249509094742" }, 35249509094742)
```

After using I am using code

```
df8["IMEI1"] = df8["IMEI1"].astype("int64")
```

to convert the column to float from object. 
I am getting error

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: '?35249509094742
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of `replace` is not correct. You can find the documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)

Below is a working example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, '?', 2, '?', 4],
                   'B': [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]})
df.replace({'A': '?'}, value='123', inplace=True)
print(df)
```

In this example, 'A' is the column name where we have a '?' as the value and we are replacing it to '123'.

This is because, the syntax of `replace` treats the dict to identify the column and the value to **find**. The value to **replace** needs to be provided as `value=`. The `inplace` argument make the changes to your original dataframe.

Hope this helps!

btw, as @Tomalak pointed out in the comments, please use code blocks to format your code in the question. Also, try to provide as much information as possible to get accurate answers.

Answer (score 0):

We have at first:

```
df8={'IMEI1':"?35249509094742"}
print(df8)
```

Replace using:

```
df8['IMEI1']=df8['IMEI1'].replace('?','')
print(df8)
```